# When observing the electrons in the double slit experiment, does the light still appear as if it were a wave?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

In the quantum double slit experiment it is said that observing the electrons causes them to appear as particles.  Does this observation which causes the electrons to "transform" into particles also cause the light behind the slits to become two beams, or do both the measurement and the wave pattern on the back wall happen simultaneously?

Additionally, is it possible that an observed particle behaves as a particle but collectively the particles behave as a wave?

Comment: I feel that it is more proper to talk about "collapsing" of wavefunction/particle into certain state, rather than about electron suddenly becoming a particle. When electron interacts with light, or being measured, electron's wavefunction collapses into certain state and you see no interference in the diffraction pattern. On the last point ("Additionally..."), each particle has inherent probability distribution for all states. Please, refer yourself to QM intro textbook for more

Comment: Thanks for answering the first question. Regarding the last point, I am aware of the probability distribution of the states of a particle, but I'm curious as to how that conclusion was reached.  Why is it thought that they have probable states and those states collapse into one definite state upon observation?

Comment: It is what is observed, not thought. In double-slit experiment, for example, through observation of interference pattern.